# Configure Jenkins/maven 3.0.4 to launch all unit tests

Tags: maven, junit, jenkins

I have great difficulty to configure maven 3.0.4 to launch all Junit tests from Jenkins.
From Jenkins this maven command is launched “clean deploy -P local”
According to the Jenkins result tests are skipped :

> INFO: --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ test-batch ---
>      [INFO] Tests are skipped

The strange thing is that locally( from eclipse) with the maven command “clean install(profile local)” all Junit tests are being launched. None of the Junit tests are skipped.

I have no idea why there is a difference between Jenkins and eclipse. I configure the pom.xml to launch all tests. I have looked at the documentation of the plugin surefire:test and google but I did not find a solution to this issue.

```
 <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>${java.version}</source>
                            <target>${java.version}</target>
                            <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>



    And 

    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                          <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                          <includes>
                             <include>**/Test*.java</include>
                             <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                          </includes>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                             <id>default-test</id>
                             <configuration>
                                <skip>false</skip>
                             </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>

                    </plugin>
```

Here is the entire pom.xml used for this project :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.projet.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>pom-corporate</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </parent>



    <groupId>com.projet.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>${project.artifactId}(${project.packaging})</name>
    <url>http://${project.artifactId}.projet.com/${config.siteUrl}</url>

    <properties>
        <test.version.package>2.2.1</test.version.package>
        <testws.version.package>2.2.1</testws.version.package>
        <testcommun.version.package>2.2.1</testcommun.version.package>
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <spring.version>2.5.6</spring.version>
        <wicket.version>1.4.18</wicket.version>
        <cxf.version>2.1.8</cxf.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>ISO-8859-15</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <config.siteUrl>website/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</config.siteUrl>
        <config.siteFullUrl>sftp://projet.com/home/groups/${project.artifactId}/htdocs/${config.siteUrl}</config.siteFullUrl>
        <config.cargoRemoteUri>service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://${config.jonasJmxServer}:${config.jonasJmxPort}/jrmpconnector_${config.cargoJonasDomainName}</config.cargoRemoteUri>
        <persistence.batch>classpath:META-INF/persistence-batch.xml</persistence.batch>
        <persistence.war>classpath:META-INF/persistence-mysql.xml</persistence.war>
    </properties>



    <scm>
        <connection>scm:svn:https://projet.com/svnroot/${project.artifactId}/trunk</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://projet.com/svnroot/${project.artifactId}/trunk</developerConnection>
    </scm>

    <!-- test resolution proxy issue -->
        <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
            <id>Nexus internal</id>
            <url>http://projet.com:8080/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Nexus releases</id>
            <url>http:// projet.com:8080/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>Nexus snapshots</id>
            <url>projet.com:8080/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <!-- Site deployment -->
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>Nexus internal</id>
            <name>Nexus repo</name>
            <url>http:// projet.com:8080/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>Nexus snapshots</id>
            <name>Nexus Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url> projet.com:8080/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

            <!-- ===================== -->
            <!-- application libraries -->
            <!-- ===================== -->



            <dependency>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>test-model</artifactId>
                <version>${test.version.package}</version>
                <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>test-application</artifactId>
                <version>${test.version.package}</version>
                <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>test-business</artifactId>
                <version>${test.version.package}</version>
                <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>test-consumer-jpa</artifactId>
                <version>${test.version.package}</version>
                <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>test-provider-wicket</artifactId>
                <version>${test.version.package}</version>
                <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>test-war</artifactId>
                <version>${test.version.package}</version>
                <type>war</type>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>test-ear</artifactId>
                <version>${test.version.package}</version>
                <classifier>${config.classifier}</classifier>
                <type>ear</type>
            </dependency>




            <!-- =================== -->
            <!-- framework libraries -->
            <!-- =================== -->

            <!-- Spring dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- spring-aop only needed in runtime -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- spring-tx includes transaction, JCA, DAO -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- spring-jdbc includes commons-exceptions, datasource management -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- spring-orm includes Hibernate and JPA support -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.6</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- commons-logging is a Spring dependency which generate failures when Jonas is runing within Eclipse -->
            <!-- so we remove this library using the provided scope -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.14</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- wicket dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
                <artifactId>wicket</artifactId>
                <version>${wicket.version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
                <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
                <version>${wicket.version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
                <artifactId>wicket-datetime</artifactId>
                <version>${wicket.version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
                <artifactId>wicket-jmx</artifactId>
                <version>${wicket.version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
                <artifactId>wicket-spring</artifactId>
                <version>${wicket.version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Gassi mock library -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.projet.clara.component</groupId>
                <artifactId>security</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- gassi jsp example uses jstl tags -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Hibernate JPA dependency -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- needed with jonas 5.1 -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- needed with jonas 5.1 -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- slf4j is used by Wicket and Hibernate Annotations 3.4 -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.6</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.b2</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- J2EE 1.4 JPA 3.0 specification -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-jpa_3.0_spec</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- hsqldb driver used for unit tests -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
                <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.0.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>test-batch</artifactId>
                <version>${test.version.package}</version>
            </dependency>


        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- test dependencies are always included -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <!-- Spring TestContext 2.5.6 only supports JUnit 4.4
            see http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-5145 -->
            <version>4.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                        <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <version>1.4</version>
                        <classifier>${config.classifier}</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>


                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                    <!-- required on continuous integration platform -->
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>ISO-8859-15</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0-beta-1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <inputEncoding>ISO-8859-15</inputEncoding>
                        <outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>ISO-8859-15</encoding>
                        <javadocVersion>1.5</javadocVersion>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>aggregate</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>aggregate</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>site</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>verify-deploy</id>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>deployer-redeploy</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>

                    <configuration>
                        <container>
                            <!-- For jonas 5 deployment, just replace with "jonas5x" -->
                            <containerId>jonas4x</containerId>
                            <type>remote</type>
                        </container>
                        <deployer>
                            <deployables>
                                <deployable>
                                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                                    <type>${project.packaging}</type>
                                    <classifier>${config.classifier}</classifier>
                                </deployable>
                            </deployables>
                        </deployer>

                        <configuration>
                            <type>runtime</type>
                            <properties>
                                <cargo.remote.uri>${config.cargoRemoteUri}</cargo.remote.uri>
                                <cargo.remote.username>${config.cargoRemoteUsername}</cargo.remote.username>
                                <cargo.remote.password>${config.cargoRemotePassword}</cargo.remote.password>
                                <cargo.jonas.server.name>${config.cargoJonasServerName}</cargo.jonas.server.name>
                                <cargo.jonas.domain.name>${config.cargoJonasDomainName}</cargo.jonas.domain.name>
                            </properties>
                        </configuration>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                      <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                      <includes>
                         <include>**/Test*.java</include>
                         <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                      </includes>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                         <id>default-test</id>
                         <configuration>
                            <skip>false</skip>
                         </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>

                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                </configuration>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <id>html</id>
                        <reports>
                            <report>javadoc</report>
                            <report>test-javadoc</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <!-- choose this profile for local deployment on windows -->
            <properties>
                <config.classifier>LOCAL</config.classifier>
                <config.jonasJmxServer>localhost</config.jonasJmxServer>
                <config.jonasJmxPort>1099</config.jonasJmxPort>
                <config.cargoRemoteUsername>jonas</config.cargoRemoteUsername>
                <config.cargoRemotePassword>jonas</config.cargoRemotePassword>

                <log.Extraction>erreurBatch.log</log.Extraction>
                <server.name>localhost</server.name>
                <file.security>/WEB-INF/security-config/security-config.xml</file.security>
                <test.level>DEBUG</test.level>
                <alt></alt>
                <wicket.mode>development</wicket.mode>
            </properties>
        </profile>
</profiles>





  <modules>
    <module>model</module>
    <module>application</module>
    <module>business</module>
    <module>consumer-jpa</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

Comment: What is the result if you run `mvn clean install` from the command line? Are the tests skipped as well?

Comment: The tests are skipped too with "mvn clean install -P local" from Jenkins.

Comment: How do you locally build your project? Do you use eclipse or do you build it from the command line? I just want to exclude the case that it is an eclipse issue. I suggest that you try to build your project from the command line and analyze the Maven logs for test executions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try specifying following in your surefire configuration?

```
<testSuite>plugin-symbolic-name-of-the-plugin-that-contains-your-tests</testSuite>
<testClass>packagetoyourclasses.*Test*</testClass>
```